# OR Tools limit visits between two nodes

Tags: python, c#, or-tools, traveling-salesman

For example lets say I have something like this:

```
solver().Add(this.solver.ActiveVar(start) == this.solver.ActiveVar(end));
```

for a specific route. this means that start index must end on end index.
What if I want to limit the number of visits that can happen in between this?

Example if the limit is 2 then only solutions that have something like so will be valid

```
start-> n1 -> n2 -> end
start -> n1 -> end
start -> end
```

Normally I would try something involving vehicle constraints, but in this case one vehicle can have multiple starts and ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1.

```cs
solver().Add(this.solver.ActiveVar(start) == this.solver.ActiveVar(end));
```

just mean that both locations must be active (i.e. visited) or unvisited (aka `0`) (i.e. are part of a disjunction).

2. What about creating a counter dimension then restrict the difference between both nodes ?
   In Python should be more or less:

```py
routing.AddConstantDimension(
1, # increase by one at each visit
42, # max count
True, # Force Start at zero
'Counter')
counter_dim = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Counter')

start = manager.NodeToIndex(start_node)
end = manager.NodeToIndex(end_node)

solver = routing.solver()

# start must be visited at most two nodes before end node
solver.Add(count_dim.CumulVar(start) + 3 >= count_dim.CumulVar(end))

# start must be visited before end
solver.Add(count_dim.CumulVar(start) <= count_dim.CumulVar(end))
```

3. Don't get your "vehicle multiple start", each vehicle has only one start. node....

Comment: Multiple starts meaning one vehicle, but a node layout like

start1->n1->n2->n3->End1->start2->n4->n5->n6->End2->startN...EndN
However I think this solution works in this case as well. Thank you very much :)